# Are Stack Exchange policies on topic?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I asked some hard questions in Meta about policies which got me banned from Meta. I asked about my stats that are not available to the user or moderator on how suspensions and bans work and why?

They say the statistical information on me is secret.  When you get suspended the next suspension you get will be longer even if whatever the reason is very minor. You can get suspended for asking an unknown to many "so so" questions that doesn't trip the questions ban which is worse because you cannot fix errors in your questions. I have been suspended years for this on a few SE sites.

Then this gets into ethics why don't they want you to see your own statistics to keep yourself from being suspended?

Is Stack Exchange's policies on topic here? because it is not in Meta.SE. Questions like these there will get you down voted to a question ban.

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what "statistical information" you asked for and were denied? You have full access to all data the ban algorithms considers, your posts and their scores. What you don't have access to is the logic the ban algorithm follows. That is not "statistical information".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is Stack Exchange's policies on topic here?

No. The correct venue is meta.stackexchange.com.

> They say the statistical information on me is secret.

If you live in the EU, you can send them a GDPR related information request -- they'll get a huge fine if they don't comply.

> When you get suspended the next suspension you get will be longer even if whatever the reason is very minor. You can get suspended for asking to many "so so" questions that doesn't trip the questions ban which is worse because you cannot fix errors in your questions. I have been suspended years for this on a few SE sites.

This is by design. I've no idea what you've been asking, but basically stop asking so so questions -- and stop bumping or trolling, if you did either of those too.

> Then this gets into ethics why don't they want you to see your own statistics to keep yourself from being suspended?

Not unusual for US-based companies. This is why the EU ended up passing the GDPR. If you don't live in Europe, either move there, or join your local advocacy group to get similar type of legislation enacted.

There's a last reason in their case: it's to avoid that trolls and spammers get the information they need to game the automated ban system.

Comment: Implore you that these policies are a secret and off topic there.

Comment: @Muze: I'm sorry I cannot help you further. From where I'm standing you dropped into Politics to whine about having been banned on Meta SE. The venue to ask about StackOverflow policies is, for better or worse, Meta SE; not here.

Comment: I just want to know. I'm guilty for being novice. I've been accused of these this because of the nature of my questions. I'm not whining and I find that offensive. What is considered bumping all my edits are improvements. I have never trolled and am offended people here are saying this about me?

Comment: When I say novice I mean in the subject like space or physics not on how this site works. I still have more to understand on the policies. You didn't answer why.

Comment: @Muze: Again, I'm sorry but I unfortunately cannot help you further. I took a quick look at your profile on a few of the sites you got banned on. Nothing obvious immediately stood out. I can only assume that you, the communities that you're banned from, or their mods have been deleting the questions, answers, or comments that got you banned in the first place. Long story short, if you get too many flags, downvotes, and close votes, then you eventually get banned. It's as simple as that. You can try sending a friendly plea by email to SO as a last resort, but methinks don't hold your breath.

Comment: See Philipps answer

Comment: I don't think GDPR is relevant here. What is kept secret is the logic behind the ban algorithm, not the user data (posts and their scores) the algorithm uses. Users do have access to that data, even if deleted. I'm not a GDPR expert, but I think the provisions regarding automated decision making are limited to actions that may have legal effects on users. I'm pretty sure getting question-banned on a Q&A site doesn't qualify.

Comment: @yannis: You are correct inasmuch as SO doesn't need to communicate the specific criteria it uses to automatically ban people, but I never suggested that they should. The GDPR draws the line at is the information about you or not. Meta information about you, such as the total number of flags, downvotes, or close votes that you've received, and whatever other aggregates might matter to trigger automated banning, as well as how much time you've spent on each page of the site and in how many sessions, is also information about you and must therefor be communicated upon request.

Answer (score 8):

No, they are not.

The "politics" of Stack Exchange as a whole is off-topic on both Politics Stack Exchange and Politics Meta Stack Exchange.

If you have questions about the Stack Exchange network which are not specific to politics stack exchange, please post them on https://meta.stackexchange.com. If you have a question about a specific stack exchange website, post on their specific meta-site.

Comment: I agree. Only, just curious: In such a case that a ban on MetaSE is in effect – a user banned on MetaSE cannot ask there – what is the *proper* way to 'escalate' this? There might be evil disruptors or genuinely hapless and helpless users being affected by such a policy. We might miss important pieces of the actual picture for *this* case above, or I might be unaware of standards of procedure, but in general?

Comment: @LangLangC In that case you could contact the Stack Exchange support via the [contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and pick "I want to appeal a code of conduct violation".

Comment: @LangLangC That doesn't work ever not even a reply. Let me know if they answer you though. Maybe it is just me.